# My button tag doesn't react to my JavaScript RoR 6

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The main goal I try to archive is when a person login in with username and password to ask for a second one which send them to their email

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>Login Shield</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'login_verify'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="Login_Form">
        <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
          <div class="messages_erros">
            <strong><li><center><%= msg %></center></li></<strong>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <strong>Code:</strong><br>
      <%= f.password_field :loginpass%>
      <br>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit :Login, class: 'log_in_button' %>
      <br>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <p>Please Check your email inbox!</p>
      <br>
      You didn't recive the code? <%= button_tag "Resend", id: "mybtn", data: { disable_with: "Sending..." }, :onclick => "resend_and_disable();", type: "button" %>
      <br>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function resend_and_disable() {
            document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = true;
           "<%= resend %>"
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = false;},Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 120000); 
        }
      </script>
      </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

also i want to disable the button after the click for sometime to block the spammers

even if i put alert on my function

```
alert("hi");
```

this also doesn't work when I press the button

my JavaScript code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function resend_and_disable() {
            document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = true;
           "<%= resend %>"
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = false;},Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 120000); 
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get you first point,

2nd point **Disable** the button after the click for sometime to block the spammers

You can try this.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let clickCounts = 0;

btn.onclick = function() { 
  if(clickCounts===2){
  
  this.setAttribute("disabled", true) 
  }
  console.log(clickCounts);
  clickCounts++;
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Here, I will disabled after 3 times</button>
```

Comment: nvm this helps me to fix both of my problems, thank you!